# Javascript: How to turn a JSON array of object back in to the Object type sharing prototypes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If you have an array of product objects created from JSON, how would you add a prototype method to the product objects so that they all point to the same method?  How would you train JavaScript to recognize all product objects in an array are instances of the same class without recreating them?

If I pull down a JSON array of Products for example, and want each product in the array to have a prototype method, how would I add the single prototype method to each copy of Product?

I first thought to have a Product constructor that takes product JSON data as a parameter and returns a new Product with prototypes, etc. which would replace the data send from the server.  I would think this would be impractical because you are recreating the objects.  We just want to add functions common to all objects.

Is it possible to `$.extend` an object's prototype properties to the JSON object so that each JSON object would refer to exactly the same functions (not a copy of)?

For example:

```
var Products = [];
Products[0] = {};
Products[0].ID = 7;
Products[0].prototype.GetID = function() { return this.ID; };
Products[1].ID = 8;
Products[1].prototype = Products[0].prototype;  // ??
```

I know that looks bad, but what if you JQuery `$.extend` the methods to each Product object prototype: create an object loaded with prototypes then `$.extend` that object over the existing Product objects?  How would you code that?  What are the better possibilities?

Comment: No such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: Seems like you'd need to do what people have to do in the strongly-typed world, and have a cooperative JSON parser that you could control somehow.  Like, if every time it needed to construct a sub-object, instead of just using `{}` it would call a callback and pass you some information about the context.  Then you could have your own code instantiate an object in whatever way you needed and return it to the parser.

Comment: You may want to read up on how JSON works.  JSON is a data exchange format, it's not an object.  You don't create an object from JSON, you parse JSON and the method creates an object from the representation.  Your solution of feeding in data to an initializer method makes much more sense.

Comment: @Mario yes, but consider what one has to do to parse JSON and instantiate objects in a strongly-typed language, such that the objects that you want are *not* type-free hash maps. If you want something like what Java people would call "beans" of some particular type(s), then there's no way that a generic JSON parser could accomodate you. You'd either need a "guidable" parser, or else you'd have to convert the hash map to the desired objects after the parse.  Such a situation arises in JavaScript when the JSON represents serialized special object types.

Comment: I suppose you could have a specialized parser that took in and analyzed the objects, and had a dictionary of types and prototypes.  Then an object with `{"type": "something", "object": {}}` would be parsed, and an object could be created with the data contained in `parsed.object` and the prototype from `Parser.types.something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm getting this all correctly, this is a more complete example of KOGI's idea:

```
// Create a person class
function Person( firstName, lastName ) {
    var aPerson = {
        firstName:  firstName,
        lastName:   lastName
    }

    // Adds methods to an object to make it of type "person"
    aPerson = addPersonMethods( aPerson );
    return aPerson;
}
function addPersonMethods( obj ) {
    obj.nameFirstLast = personNameFirstLast;
    obj.nameLastFirst = personNameLastFirst;
    return obj;
}
function personNameFirstLast() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
function personNameLastFirst() {
    return this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName;
}
```

So, with this structure, you are defining the methods to be added in the addPersonMethods function.  This way, the methods of an object are defined in a single place and you can then do something like this:

```
// Given a variable "json" with the person json data
var personWithNoMethods = JSON.parse( json );    // Use whatever parser you want
var person = addPersonMethods( personWithNoMethods );
```

Comment: This could probably be reworked to feed the personWithNoMethods variable in as a parameter for a new person object as well.  Maybe by doing a pseudo-overload on the constructor by checking if the first parameter is an object so you could assign `var person = new person( personWithNoMethods );`

Comment: I would assume addPersonMethods wouldn't need to return an obj since you are modifying what was passed to you.  However, you could create a new object in addPersonMethods then return the obj without modifying the original.  aPerson = addPersonMethods( aPerson); has the same effect.  You could just do addPersonMethods( aPerson); without the aPerson = in front.

Comment: This definitely has a method to modify an existing object with identical references to the same method.

Comment: Hey, Dr.Zim! I'm coming back to this question several years later to give an update: The ability to define a prototype within an object literal is part of the upcoming ECMAScript 6 feature set as `var obj = { __proto__: theProtoObj }`.

Answer (score 2):

For one, you're not modifying the `Products[0].prototype`, you're modifying `Object.prototype`, which will put that function on the prototype of all objects, as well as making it enumerable in every for loop that touches an Object.

Also, that isn't the proper way to modify a prototype, and `({}).prototype.something` will throw a TypeError as `.prototype` isn't defined. You want to set it with `({}).__proto__.something`.

If you want it to be a certain instance you need to create that instance, otherwise it will be an instance of Object.

You probably want something like:

```
var Product = function(ID) {
    if (!this instanceof Product)
        return new Product(ID);

    this.ID = ID;

    return this;
};

Product.prototype.GetID = function() { 
    return this.ID;
};
```

Then, fill the array by calling `new Product(7)` or whatever the ID is.

Comment: Better explanation then my answer but along the same lines.

Comment: This would go along the lines of recreating the array, which is a start.  I would really like to decorate existing objects with references to an existing method.

Comment: You can modify the prototype of the Object, but it does affect all of the other Objects. I'd either do recreate it using this, or as Pointy said, intercept the actual parsing of the Object and handle it then.

Answer (score 2):

First, one problem is that `prototype` methods are associated when the object is *created*, so assigning to an object's `prototype` will not work:

```
var Products = [];
Products[0] = {};
Products[0].prototype.foo = function () { return 'hello' } // ***

Products[0].foo(); // call to undefined function
```

(`***` Actually, the code fails here, because `prototype` is undefined.)

So in order to attach objects, you'll need to assign actual functions to the object:

```
Products[0].foo = function () { return 'hello'; };
```

You can create a helper function to do so:

```
var attachFoo = (function () { // Create a new variable scope, so foo and
                               // bar is not part of the global namespace

    function foo() { return this.name; }
    function bar() { return 'hello'; }

    return function (obj) {
        obj.foo = foo;
        obj.bar = bar;
        return obj; // This line is actually optional,
                    // as the function /modifies/ the current
                    // object rather than creating a new one
    };

}());

attachFoo(Products[0]);
attachFoo(Products[1]);

// - OR -
Products.forEach(attachFoo);
```

By doing it this way, your `obj.foo`s and `obj.bar`s will all be referencing the same `foo()` and `bar()`.

Comment: That is great.  From what I understand, previous answers showed how to create new instances of an object based on a constructor, but that assumes the JSON parser would use the constructors to create the objects.  This modifies objects created by the JSON parser to have the same method shared between them.  Very nice.

Comment: This works, but it's worth noting that it's not referencing the same `foo` and the same `bar` explicitly. Instead, it copies the function to the object, so if the function is updated within attachFoo, it won't update the functions in objects it has already been called on. Not a huge deal, but should be clear. Best demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/fR6AE/

Answer (score 1):

You could do this...

```
function product( )
{
   this.getId = product_getId;

    // -- create a new product object
}

function product_getId( )
{
   return this.id;
}
```

This way, although you will have several instances of the product class, they all point to the instance of the function.

Comment: So if the JSON parser created the object already, just add properties to those objects that point to an existing function.  I assume this is by reference and not making a copy of the function.

Comment: Yes, functions are by reference.

Comment: @kogi: Each time you assign `product_getId` it is copied, not referenced.

Comment: @Robert, the function is copied?

Comment: @kogi: copied probably wasn't the best choice of words. If you redefine `product_getId()`, it won't update anything already pointing to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Could try doing something like this (without jquery)
Basic prototypal object:

```
function Product(id){
    this.id = id;
}
Product.prototype.getId() = function(){return this.id;};

var Products = [];
Products[0] = new Product(7);
Products[1] = new Product(8);
Products[2] = new Product(9);

alert(Products[2].getId());
```

Comment: This would recreate the array created by the JSON parser, but it's a start.  I would really like to decorate existing objects with references to existing methods so as to not recreate the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

IMO I found a pretty good answer right here:

[Return String from Cross-domain AJAX Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376623/return-string-from-cross-domain-ajax-request)

> ...I could serialize my
>   data in the service as a JSON string
>   and then further wrap that in JSONP
>   format? I guess when it comes over to
>   the client it would give the JSON
>   string to the callback function.
>   That's not a bad idea. I guess I would
>   also have the option of sending a
>   non-JSON string which might allow me
>   to just use eval in the callback
>   function to create new Person objects.
>   I'm thinking this would be a more
>   efficient solution in both speed and
>   memory usage client-side.

Comment: It may present a way to intercept the JSON conversion to do it manually, but I am really looking for a way to decorate existing objects with a parent object so they inherit the parent object's methods without having a copy of the methods for each object.