# Return String from Cross-domain AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm looking for a way to return a single JSON/JSONP string from a cross-domain "AJAX" request.  Rather than request the string and have JQuery return it as a generic object automatically, I want to get a hold of the string BEFORE that conversion happens. The goal here is to parse it myself so I can turn it straight into new objects of a certain type (e.g. a Person object).

So, just to make this clear, I don't want any string-to-generic-object conversion going on behind the scenes and this must work using a different domain.

Here's a non-working example of what I would like to do:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.someOtherDomain.com/GetPerson',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: parseToPerson
});

function parseToPerson( textToParse ) {
    // I think I can do this part, I just want to get it working up to this point
}
```

I'm perfectly happy if JQuery isn't involved in the solution, as long as it works.  I would prefer to use JQuery, though.  From what I've read, the javascript techniques used to get JSONP data (dynamically creating a script element) would probably work, but I can't seem to get that to work for me.  I control the domain that I am requesting data from and I can get the data if I change the dataType in the AJAX call to 'JSONP', so I know that is working.

Comment: I managed to get a JSONP "request" to work without using JQuery.  The method involves adding a script tag with src pointing to the url that sends back the data. It wont work for me unless I use type="application/x-javascript".  This runs it right away and so the data gets created as a generic object before I can do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is being retrieved from another domain, you will need to use JSONP (there are other options, but JSONP is by far the easiest if you control the service). The jQuery call will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // type: 'GET', --> this is the default, you don't need this line
    url: 'http://www.someOtherDomain.com/GetPerson',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: parseToPerson
});
```

The actual request that goes to your service will be `http://www.someOtherDomain.com/GetPerson?callback=arbitrary_function_name`. On the service side, you will need to return data like this:

```
arbitrary_function_name("the string (or JSON data) that I want to return");
```

So you'll need to inspect the querystring parameters, get the value of the `callback` parameter, and echo it out as if you're calling a Javascript function with that name (which you are), passing in the value you want to provide through the service. Your `success` function will then get called with the data your service provided.

If you're deserializing the returned data into a Javascript object, you might be better off returning JSON data than a string, so the data your service returns might look like this:

```
arbitrary_function_name({
    "name":"Bob Person", 
    "age":27, 
    "etc":"More data"
});
```

That way you don't have to worry about parsing the string - it'll already be in a Javascript object that's easy to use to initialize your object.

Comment: So, you're saying I could serialize my data in the service as a JSON string and then further wrap that in JSONP format? I guess when it comes over to the client it would give the JSON string to the callback function.  That's not a bad idea.  I guess I would also have the option of sending a non-JSON string which might allow me to just use eval in the callback function to create new Person objects.  I'm thinking this would be a more efficient solution in both speed and memory usage client-side.  I think you have found my answer, my friend, thank you.

Comment: @BDawg - When you use JSONP, you're actually running the code your service returns. So you don't need to use `eval` - when your service spits out `callback({"some":"data"});`, the `success` function is actually receiving a Javascript object. So you could, in theory, return full-fledged Person objects - but you'd separate concerns better by returning data and instantiating the person on the client side.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Ah, so that wasn't what you meant.  Well, I found an answer as a result of this anyway.  The JSONP code would be feeding a string containing Javascript code to the callback function rather than an object in this case.  So, the service would be spitting out something more like this: `callback("[new Person(\"John\":\"Doe\")]");`  I'm not sure if this is considered a bad practice or not, but it certainly does answer my question as to how it is possible.

Comment: @BDawg - Well, if you wanted to do it like that, you could just as easily have the service code make something like `callback(new Person("John", "Doe"))` - the extra step of serializing and deserializing the string is unnecessary. But that makes the service really tightly coupled with the client-side code - it's much cleaner to have the service provide data and have the client-side code create the object.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Ah, good point.  I wouldn't need to send it to a callback as a string that way.  What do you think about sending it as a typical JSON string and using a regular expression to insert the "new Person", re-order the properties (just in case) and then remove property names?  That would cut out using generic objects still and avoid making the service and client too tightly coupled, I would think.  Would it be faster and/or lighter on memory, or just an unnecessary step?

Comment: @BDawg - I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/pExvB/ - I don't see any benefit to printing an escaped JSON string and then parsing it. IMHO, the only reason to return anything other than a Javascript object would be if you had a lot of data to return and needed a more compact format.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Oh cool, I didn't even notice that jsfiddle had AJAX tests included in it.  Yeah, this is how I did it before.  My thinking was that by skipping the step where we are parsing from text to generic objects, it might be faster but it doesn't seem that is going to make a difference unless we pass Javascript code straight to the web page.  As you pointed out, though, that tightly couples service to the client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this will work in conjuction with jsonp, but maybe [converters](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Converters) is what you're looking for?

```
$.ajax(url, {
  dataType: "person",
  converters: {
    "text person": function(textValue) {
      return parseToPerson(textValue);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried it out and JQuery is trying to use XMLHttpRequest to fetch the data.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work with data coming from another domain.  Thanks though.  Any other ideas?